# Retrieve MySQL multiple Query with PHP and Process

Tags: php, python, mysql, sorting, structure

So far I have this code:

```
<?php
include('config.php');

$sql = "SELECT senderID as receiverID, msg, time
        FROM msg
        WHERE senderID = 1";

$result = mysql_query($sql);

if (!$result) {
    echo "Could not successfully run query ($sql) from DB: " . mysql_error();
    exit;
}

if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
    echo "No rows found, nothing to print so am exiting";
    exit;
}

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row["receiverID"];
    echo $row["msg"];
    echo $row["time"];
}


mysql_free_result($result);
?>
```

Now this simply fetch's the info and stuff, it works the only problem is the processing part. See, I can probably do this so easily in Python, but I am new in PHP, so, if someone could help me, because this is a example of the thing I get returned:

> 1Hello! How are you?!?!?!876765981admin to user 3574769

Now, I actually was wondering how I would be able to serperate these into its own variable or just print seperately, I am not quiet sure, this is how its suppose to look for a python thing:

> firstRow = ['1','Hello! How are you?!?!?!','876765981']
>
> secondRow = ['1','admin to user 3','574769']

Now, I am not so sure about the php structure or code for this.

Comment: If you want to just spit out each `$row`, you can do `print_r($row);`.  Also, it's best to use mysqli(http://php.net/mysqli) for queries, not mysql.  It is generally considered to be more secure (and the mysql_* extensions are due to be deprecated).

Comment: ok, thanks for your input on that, but how would I change it to mysqli querys? And also, about the print_r($row) what do you mean? I only get this now: **1Array ( [receiverID] => 1 [msg] => Hello! How are you?!?!?! [time] => 87676598 ) Hello! How are you?!?!?!Array ( [receiverID] => 1 [msg] => Hello! How are you?!?!?! [time] => 87676598 ) 87676598Array ( [receiverID] => 1 [msg] => Hello! How are you?!?!?! [time] => 87676598 ) 1Array ( [receiverID] => 1 [msg] => admin to user 3 [time] => 574769 ) admin to user 3Array ( [receiverID] => 1 [msg] => .......** and I cut the rest out...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In php,what you got was:

```
[
    1 => ["receiverId"=>'1',
          "msg"=>'Hello! How are you?!?!?!',
           "time"=>'876765981'],
    2 =>  ["receivedId"=>'1',
           "msg"=>'admin to user 3',
            "time"=>'574769']
]
```

To get the first row

```
$firstrow = $result[1]
```

To print it

```
echo $firstrow["msg"];
```

The `$result` is a nested associative array

Comment: Thanks, I will try this today and let you know!